# Error at or near square brackets - Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL query which is:

```
insert into client (email, name) values ('johndoe@email.com', 'johnDoe');
insert into client_settings (client_id, data) values (currval('client_id_seq'), 0);
insert into client_verify (client_id, dataFields) values (currval('client_id_seq'), json_build_object('data1', ['a1', 'a2'], 'data2', ['b1', 'b2']) );
```

But I'm getting an error stating SQL Error [42601]: syntax error at or near "[".

The last json object(i.e., the dataFields) when inserted into the DB it should look like:

```
{"data1": ["a1", "a2"], "data2": ["b1", "b2"]}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there something that I'm missing or a different way to do that?

Comment: Can we see the create table for the last table ?

Comment: it has id - int, client_id - int and dataFields - jsonb @VBoka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After good research I [found documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) to put 'Array' in front of those like:

```
json_build_object('data1', Array['a1', 'a2'], 'data2', Array['b1', 'b2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need :

```
insert into client_verify (client_id, dataFields) 
values (currval('client_id_seq'), json_build_object('data1', 'a1, a2', 'data2', 'b1, b2')  );
```

Please try this:

```
insert into client_verify (client_id, dataFields) 
values (currval('client_id_seq')
        , json_build_object('data1', '["a1", "a2"]', 'data2', '["b1", "b2"]'));
```

Here you can check how you need to add your string:
https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output

The **UNESCAPE** is the option you need

Here is a demo :

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=40db2949a4431b31e72bee2ebe2e215a)

Comment: This does not give me an array like this ["a1", "a2"]

Comment: Hi @iCodeByte I have made a demo also... maybe it will help... cheers

Comment: Hi @iCodeByte yes it does: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=496515f55882b3c56367221e5624e4eb